# Preserving Column Order - Python Pandas and Column Concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

So my google-fu doesn't seem to be doing me justice with what seems like should be a trivial procedure.

In Pandas for Python I have 2 datasets, I want to merge them.  This works fine using .concat.  The issue is, .concat reorders my columns.  From a data retrieval point of view, this is trivial.  From a "I just want to open the file and quickly see the most important column" point of view, this is annoying.

```
File1.csv
Name    Username    Alias1 
Tom     Tomfoolery   TJZ
Meryl   MsMeryl      Mer
Timmy   Midsize      Yoda

File2.csv
Name    Username   Alias 1   Alias 2
Bob     Firedbob   Fire      Gingy
Tom     Tomfoolery  TJZ      Awww

Result.csv
    Alias1 Alias2   Name    Username
0   TJZ    NaN      Tom     Tomfoolery
1   Mer    NaN      Meryl   MsMeryl
2   Yoda   NaN      Timmy   Midsize
0   Fire   Gingy    Bob     Firedbob
1   TJZ    Awww     Tom     Tomfoolery
```

The result is fine, but in the data-file I'm working with I have 1,000 columns.  The 2-3 most important are now in the middle.  Is there a way, in this toy example, I could've forced "Username" to be the first column and "Name" to be the second column, preserving the values below each all the way down obviously.

Also as a side note, when I save to file it also saves that numbering on the side (0 1 2 0 1).  If theres a way to prevent that too, that'd be cool.  If not, its not a big deal since it's a quick fix to remove.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the concatenated DataFrame is `df`, you can perform the reordering of columns as follows:

```
important = ['Username', 'Name']
reordered = important + [c for c in df.columns if c not in important]
df = df[reordered]
print df
```

Output:

```
     Username   Name Alias1 Alias2
0  Tomfoolery    Tom    TJZ    NaN
1     MsMeryl  Meryl    Mer    NaN
2     Midsize  Timmy   Yoda    NaN
0    Firedbob    Bob   Fire  Gingy
1  Tomfoolery    Tom    TJZ   Awww
```

The list of numbers `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1]` is the index of the DataFrame. To prevent them from being written to the output file, you can use the `index=False` option in `to_csv()`:

```
df.to_csv('Result.csv', index=False, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Is it more or less pythonic to comping the firsy two lines of your solution into one line, such as:
`reorderd = [['username', 'name'] + col for col in summary.columns if col not in ['username', 'name']]`