# Column order in pandas.concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I do as below:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
frames = [data1, data2]
data = pd.concat(frames)
data


   a    b
0   2   1
1   2   1
2   2   1
0   2   1
1   2   1
2   2   1
```

The data column order is in alphabet order. Why is it so?
and how to keep the original order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving Column Order - Python Pandas and Column Concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533944/preserving-column-order-python-pandas-and-column-concat)

Comment: Dict arent ordered, so why should the columns be ordered?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are creating DataFrames out of dictionaries. Dictionaries are a unordered which means the keys do not have a specific order. So

```
d1 = {'key_a': 'val_a', 'key_b': 'val_b'}
```

and

```
d2 = {'key_b': 'val_b', 'key_a': 'val_a'}
```

are (probably) the same.

In addition to that I assume that pandas sorts the dictionary's keys descending by default (unfortunately I did not find any hint in the docs in order to prove that assumption) leading to the behavior you encountered.

So the basic motivation would be to resort / reorder the columns in your DataFrame. You can do this [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148611/3991125):

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
frames = [data1, data2]
data = pd.concat(frames)

print(data)

cols = ['b' , 'a']
data = data[cols]

print(data)
```

Comment: Will this "just work" in Python 3.7? Dicts are guaranteed to maintain their order.

Comment: As an improvement, you don't have to manually specify the columns. You can just do... `combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])[df1.columns]`. This does assume you already have a data frame with columns in the order you want. But that was my case.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from version 0.23.0, you can prevent the concat() method to sort the returned DataFrame.  For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'a' : [1, 1, 1], 'b' : [2, 2, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
```

A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default.

Comment: To demonstrate `sort=False` vs `sort=True` the last line should be `df = pd.concat([df2, df1], sort=False)`. Then the columns will be in different order depending on `sort`.

Answer (score 5):

```
def concat_ordered_columns(frames):
    columns_ordered = []
    for frame in frames:
        columns_ordered.extend(x for x in frame.columns if x not in columns_ordered)
    final_df = pd.concat(frames)    
    return final_df[columns_ordered]       

# Usage
dfs = [df_a,df_b,df_c]
full_df = concat_ordered_columns(dfs)
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, this was nice to have for my case where the DataFrames were being created from already-existing CSV files.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the original DataFrames with OrderedDicts

```
from collections import OrderedDict

odict = OrderedDict()
odict['b'] = [1, 1, 1]
odict['a'] = [2, 2, 2]
data1 = pd.DataFrame(odict)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(odict)
frames = [data1, data2]
data = pd.concat(frames)
data


    b    a
0   1    2
1   1    2
2   1    2
0   1    2
1   1    2
2   1    2
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also specify the order like this :

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1], 'a' : [2, 2, 2]})
listdf = [data1, data2]
data = pd.concat(listdf)
sequence = ['b','a']
data = data.reindex(columns=sequence)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is firstly make the columns same order then concat:

```
df2=df2[df1.columns]
df=pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=0)
```