# Pandas dataframe columns unexpectedly out of order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I encountered a rather unexpected result today with a pandas dataframe.

My script takes genome sequence data (in fasta format) as input and calculates several basic metrics. I store those metrics in a pandas dataframe.

The script starts by defining an empty dataframe with headers:

```
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Assembly','Size','#Contigs','#Contigs > 3000','N50','Longest_contig'])
```

The main body of the script then loops through all genome files and calculates all the metrics listed in the headers. That all works just fine. I then add the metrics for the genome assembly to the stats_df dataframe using these two lines:

```
new_df_row = pd.DataFrame({'Assembly':[assembly_name],'Size':[assembly_size_in_Mbp],'#Contigs':[num_of_contigs],'#Contigs > 3000':[greater_than_3000_count],'N50':[n50],'Longest_contig':[longest_contig]})
stats_df = pd.concat([stats_df,new_df_row],ignore_index=True)
```

The unexpected behaviour is when I view stats_df the columns are ordered:
#Contigs, #Contigs > 3000, Assembly, Longest_contig, N50, Size.

This is different to the order of the entries in the empty dataframe a the start and in each new row added. The metrics are all in the right place, I'm just wondering what causes the columns to move around like that?

Comment: Ah - seems it's a result of a difference in python version. It was trying to run under python 2.7, I needed to specify python 3. Still not sure why it causes the column shift though?

Comment: How are you outputting the dataframe? It certainly looks like the method you are using is sorting the columns alphabetically

Comment: Ah, based on your comment, I would say it is down to the way `dict` is handled in the different versions of Python. In 2.7, the keys are returned in arbitrary order, whereas in Python 3, it was determined the `OrderedDict` implementation is actually faster, so the original order is retained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that for `new_df_row` you're using a dictionary to create the data frame. Dictionaries are unordered (in Python 3.6 and below), so the keys do not have any fix order. [This article](https://saturncloud.io/blog/why-the-column-order-is-changing-while-appending-pandas-dataframes/) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046931/column-order-in-pandas-concat) explain the issue nicely.

To fix it, you could upgrade to Python 3.7 which has ordered dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't specified which python version to use (oops!) but I also didn't realise that dictionaries were unordered in older versions of python. A lesson learned today! :)